# Exit always called - variable precedence

Tags: bash

I'm new to bash and having an issue where `exit` is always called in my script. Consider this simple code:

```
if [[ "$x" -ge 1 && "$x" -le 4 ]]; then
    /export/home/scripts/script1.sh \
    "$x" \
    || echo "Error.. something went wrong." && exit 1
fi
```

How can I handle errors, considering `&&` takes precedence over `||` ?

Using GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this wiki article about boolean algebra helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: use an `else` to break the statement up.  Or enclosures: `(...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
if [[ "$x" -ge 1 && "$x" -le 4 ]]; then
    /export/home/scripts/script1.sh \
    "$x" \
    || { echo "Error.. something went wrong." && exit 1 ; }
fi
```

Note : I used `{ ; }`, instead of `()`, because `()` will open your command in a subshell, so it will not exit.

Answer (score 4):

`&&` and `||` have the same precedence in shell; the implicit parenthesization is `(a || b) && c`, not `a || (b && c)`. Mixing `||` and `&&` in the same list is rarely a good idea; use an explicit `if` statement.

```
if [[ "$x" -ge 1 && "$x" -le 4 ]]; then
  if ! /export/home/scripts/script1.sh "$x"; then
      echo "Error.. something went wrong"
      exit 1
  fi
fi
```

For arithmetic comparisons, prefer the arithemetic command `((...))` over `[[ ... ]]` for readability.

```
if (( x >= 1 && x <= 4 )); then
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use braces to regroup commands without creating a new subshell :

```
{ true || false; } && echo true || echo false # echoes true
{ false || false; } && echo true || echo false # echoes false
```

Its syntax is pretty annoying : the opening brace must be followed by a space (or another character of `$IFS`, such as a linefeed or a tab), and the closing brace must be preceded by a linefeed or a `;`, denoting the end of the last command of the block.

Parenthesis don't have those difficulties, but they will execute their instructions in a subshell, which has multiple other effects :

- calling `exit` will only exit the subshell, not the shell running your script : `(exit)` is a no-op
- updating variables will only apply to the subshell and will have no effect on the values known to your script : `a=0;( (( a++ )) ; echo $a) ; echo $a` will echo 1 from the subshell, then 0 from the outer shell.

Comment: I feel like my example doesn't really makes sense in the context of OP, but I can't seem to find a better one. Feel free to comment or even edit my answer if you have a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer doing explicit tests on scripts using `if` so that I can clean up after myself if things go pear shaped. Helps keep the code looking cleaner, too.

```
if [[ "$x" -ge 1 && "$x" -le 4 ]]; then
    if ! /export/home/scripts/script1.sh "$x"; then
        err="Error.. something went wrong."
        test -t 0 && echo "$err" >&2        # send errors to stderr if on terminal
        logger -p local0.critical -t $(hostname -s) "$err"       # send to syslog
        # You could even add some code here to clean up after script1.sh.
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```